# I cant use two scanf function to Enter the letters

Tags: c++, c

Why I cant   use two scanf function to Enter the characters

for example

```
char a;
char b;
printf("a");
scanf("%c", &a);
printf("%c", a);
scanf("%c", &b);

printf("%c", b);
```

There are many solutions, but I want to know what is the reason why the2 scanf function does not work in characters

Comment: what error u r getting

Answer (score 2):

When you enter in a single character you're actually sending two characters to the program: the character you pressed and a newline character from when you pressed the Enter key.

Suppose you pressed "s" then Enter.  The first `scanf` would read only the "s", leaving the newline in the input buffer.  The second `scanf` will then immediately read the newline, which is then printed by the second `printf`.

If you entered two or more characters and pressed Enter, for example "abc" then Enter, the first `scanf` will read the "a" and the second `scanf` will immediately read the "b".  The "c" and the newline will be left in the buffer when the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure code of scanf is like that

```
scanf()
    int readCount = 0;
    copy data to buffer until newline
    clear the keyboard buffer until newline
    match the pattern and write to the vargs
    for every pattern matched, readCount ++
    return readCount;
```

Since every scanf will try to parse and clear the keyboard buffer until newline. so you cannot type 2 chars in the same line.

You can 2 easy solution for this.

```
1) scanf( "%c%c", &a, &b )
```

which is not general purpose

```
2) std::cin >> a >> b;
```

which is general purpose, but from my experience, this method is a bit slower than scanf.